# Selection of Dependency version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Consider there are two dependencies(a and b) in main app. In main app we directly kept one version (say 1.0.0) of dependency 'a', and we kept dependency 'b' also. But in dependency 'b' there contains  higher version of dependency 'a'(say 1.0.1). So when running the main app, which version of dependency 'a' will be considered.?

Comment: i'm not sure if the dependency inside b will even be available to your app

Comment: is android studio will take all the dependency in a stack and consider the latest version? if there are same dependency with different verison?

Comment: android studio uses gradle, so i don't think it matters how android studio sees it, it depends on what gradle does. what gradle will do here, i'm not sure. i don't think you can have two dependencies with different versions, but i could be wrong, no idea

Comment: The newest version of the dependency is used. This is Gradle's default strategy, and is often an appropriate choice as long as versions are backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, It will always take the latest version of dependency in all available versions, you can avoid that by specifying force to let `gradle` know to use the specific version.

```
implementation("a:1.0.0"){
   force = true
}
```

Also you can check the version used in your dependency tree, or external libraries folder